# What's the best way to implement a counter that counts up when a different counter hits certain milestones

Tags: c#, scripting

i'm trying to make a clicker game in unity, where for every 100 "views" a dollar is generated, i'm not sure as to how to tackle this problem. i have tried using an update function that adds 1 to the dollar counter for every multiple of 100, but that misses out counting up if the number lands on say 101, i'm lost on what else to try as i'm a beginner really in this kind of code and i'm not really sure where to look for how to do this any other way.

Answer (score 0):

One potential way to set this up would be to set a separate *Limbo_Views* variable alongside implied *Total_Views* and *Total_Earnings* variables to keep track of how far towards the next 100 view milestone the counter is or has surpassed

For example...

```
public class Video{

    public int Total_Views;
    public int Total_Earnings;
    private int Limbo_Views;

    public Video() {
        Total_Views = 0;
        Total_Earnings = 0;
        Limbo_Views = 0;
    }

    public void addViews(int views) {
        Total_Views += views;           // <-- add views to total
        Limbo_Views += views;           // <- add views to limbo view count
        if(Limbo_Views >= 100) {        // <-- if there 100+ views in limbo...
            int dollarsToAdd = Limbo_Views / 100;  // <-- determine how many dollars should be paid out
            Total_Earnings += dollarsToAdd; // <-- add that amount to earnings
            Limbo_Views -= (dollarsToAdd * 100); // <-- decrement limbo views to reflect views that have been accounted for
        }
    }
}
```

This should be able to handle any positive number you throw at it in terms of adding views and accounting for their earnings.

Let me know if you have any additional questions!